# Eigenvectors span linear space of dimension 1

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I need to show whether or not eigenvectors of the matrix below span a linear space of dimension 1.

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Looking at the matrix you can see that it has the eigenvalue 1 with algebraic multiplicity 2 and geometric multiplicity 1.

Does this mean that the eigenvector spans a linear space of dimension 1? I am unsure what is meant by this.

Comment: Geometric multiplicity means the dimension of the eigenspace...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, $\lambda = 1$ is the only eigenvalue. Actually, the geometric multiplicity of the eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$ is equal to the dimension of the eigenspace $V(\lambda)$. So yes, the eigenvector associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$ spans the linear (eigen)space $V(\lambda)$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. All eigenvalues are one, so if it had two independent eigenvectors, the matrix with respect to this basis would be the identity. However this matrix is not similar to the identity, because it does not equal the identity.